# making my function more concise

Tags: python

I've been trying different ways to make this function more concise, or as my friend calls it 'slick',  any help here?

```
def craps():
    from random import randint
    dice = 0
    loop = 0
    while loop < 1:
        d1 = randint(1,6)
        d2 = randint(1,6)
        roll = d1 + d2
        dice += 1
        print(d1, d2)
        while dice == 1:
            first=roll
            if roll in {2,3,12}:
                loop += 1
                return 0
            elif roll in {7,11}:
                loop += 1
                return 1
            else:
                break
        while dice != 1:
            if first==roll:
                loop += 1
                return 1
            elif roll==7:
                loop += 1
                return 0
            else:
                break
```

Comment: Why write loops that will definitely return or break in the first iteration? Are you confusing `while` with `if` ?

Comment: Those two inner `while` loops are `if` in disguise.

Comment: A concise statement of your requirements would be helpful

Comment: codereview is the site you're looking for.

Comment: @khelwood when i was running my code it would print the first pair of dice rolls and then get hung up on checking the loop, this was the only way to stop that loop

Comment: It's hard to know what to recommend to make code more concise when the starting code doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre didnt know that was a site! thank you

Comment: @GeorgeJacobFlamburis There's no point having a loop if you're not going to let it loop.

Comment: Can you explain what the code is supposed to be doing?

Comment: I was lazy: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ now you have the address.

Comment: @Keatinge the function essentially plays a game of craps and keeps going untill you win or lose

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rules IIUC are: on first roll 2, 3, 12 lose and 7 or 11 wins. Otherwise if you repeat the same total before a 7 arrives you win, if 7 comes first instead you lose.

In code I'd write:

```
def roll():
    d1 = randint(1, 6)
    d2 = randint(1, 6)
    print((d1, d2))
    return d1 + d2

def game():
    first = roll()
    if first in (2, 3, 12):
        return 0
    if first in (7, 11):
        return 1
    while True:
        other = roll()
        if other == first:
            return 1
        elif other == 7:
            return 0
```

Note that coincise is not a good target, target is readability. Often making code shorter improves readability, but not always (see code golfing competitions... admittedly funny to code but not something you to want to deal with in production).

Comment: while running your code I expected to get (2 5 /n 1). but i got                  (2, 5)
(1, 3)
(1, 4)
(4, 4)
(6, 4)
(2, 1)
(4, 1)
(4, 4)
(5, 1)
(6, 4)
(3, 6)
(2, 5)
1

Comment: @GeorgeJacobFlamburis: the first version I posted was buggy... the code originally read `if roll in (2, 3, 12)` instead of `if first in (2, 3, 12)` and this unfortunately in Python silently return `False` without any error (it's checking for the function object being in the list).